# the nearest distance according to a database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, google-maps

I add stations in google maps, and I calculate the distance to the nearest station.

```
int distance = 999999999;

    for(double[] point : StationTram) { 
        LatLng to = new LatLng(point[0],point[1]);
        //Calculating the distance in meters
        int distanceLambda = (int)SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);

    if ( distanceLambda < distance ) { 
        distance = distanceLambda ;
        Latitude1 = point[0];
        Longitude1 = point[1];
    }
```

I want to add the state of the station eg ON and OFF, I have a table named Stations in my database, two columns Station name and the state,
I want that, depending on the state I calculate the distance to the nearest station.

I do not know how to do, I'd like some help !
Thank you

Comment: So, what is the problem that stops you doing this?

Comment: I do not know how to do, I'd like some help

Comment: you can retrieve data from DB.